# Why are all good movies restricted in Egypt?

Tags: copyright

Starting from youtube movies to other websites like crackle, all of them are restricted in Egyp. I provided some screenshots as examples but almost all websites with good Hollywood movies and Canadian series/shows are restricted.
If a few movies are restricted, I would understand this. If some of the websites are restricted, I would understand this too. Since I can't watch anything, I feel like it's an agreement between countries (not just companies or copyright issues). So, I would like to know the reason why Egypt is restricted from watching movies? I would appreciate it if the answer contains a link to the agreement or the official document that states Egypt cannot watch movies.

If I unlocked this geo-restriction (regardless of whether it's legal here or not), who will be annoyed? Egyptian Gov? US Gov? The company that made the movie? The website that hosts the movie? Something else?

Comment: Welcome to MoviesTV, is this question suited for this site ? Isn't it a question more legal than about movies ? (I know your issue concern movie but for me it more like a legal question). Maybe give a try at law stack exchange ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not about copyright so much as Egypt's [local laws about censorship and child protection](https://www.shandpartners.com/movie-rating-system-in-egypt/).

> According to Article 2 of Law 430 of 1955, it is prohibited to distribute, rent and/or sell, by any mean, directly or indirectly, any of audio or audio-video works without obtaining authorization from the Ministry of Culture.
>
> In this regard, according to Article 2 of the Executive Regulation of Law 430 of 1995, the General Department of Censorship on Audio Video Works (the “**Department**”) of the Ministry of Culture is the competent authority having the power to authorise the distribution, rental and/or sell of any audio and/or audio-video works.

Further specifications on that page note the prohibition on children seeing media that "addresses basic instincts or beautifies behavior contrary to the society values, or leads them to delinquency" and restricts "(i) intense violence; (ii) crimes; (iii) sexual situations; (iv) suggestive dialogue; and (v) coarse or crude language". The burden of enforcing this is on the "directors of movie theaters and similar public places", who must "announce at the movie theater and in all their advertising that the show is prohibited to children. Such announcements shall be very explicit, clear and in Arabic language", with steep fines levied per child and per theater or "similar public place".

Because the regulatory burden is so great on producers, distributors, and theater owners, it makes sense that less-than-mainstream media may not undergo the approvals that would allow it to be seen or streamed in Egypt.